# How to pause in Dragon Age 2 Demo during combat?

Tags: ps3, dragon-age-2

How do I pause in the Dragon Age 2 Demo during combat? It says it can be done somehow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're thinking of the PC pause, where you could press <kbd>space</kbd> to pause and assign commands to your main and allies, the console equivalent is the radial menu.

Pause the game by pressing the <kbd>L2</kbd> button to bring up the radial menu. From there, you can cycle through your characters by pressing <kbd>L1</kbd> or <kbd>R1</kbd> and issue orders. When you close the radial menu, the orders will be executed.